# KeyError with Python dictionary

Tags: python, debugging, interpreter, keyerror

I've been practicing on a [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish#The_register) interpreter and am stuck on an error I'm getting. The problematic code seems to be here:

```
import sys
from random import randint

file = sys.argv[1]
code = open(file)
program = code.read()

print(str(program))

stdin = sys.argv[2]
prgmlist = program.splitlines()
length = len(prgmlist)
prgm = {}
for x in range(0,length-1):
    prgm[x+1] = list(prgmlist[x])
```

The goal here was to take the code and put it into a sort of grid, so that each command could be taken and computed separately. By grid, I mean a map to a list:

```
{line1:["code","code","code"]
 line2:["code","code","code"]
 line3:...}
```

and so on.

However, when I try to retrieve a command using `cmd = prgm[y][x]` it gives me `KeyError: 0`.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abest/Documents/Python/><>_Interpreter.py", line 270, in <module>
    cmd = prgm[cmdy][cmdx]
KeyError: 0
```

And a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3rYanwrh) of the entire code.

The input is the hello world program from the wiki page:

```
!v"hello, world"r!
 >l?!;o
```

Comment: You should add the code that is causing issue as well? As well as the complete traceback for the same.

Comment: Also, you should let us know what your input/output is.

Comment: Give us examples of what your input looks like.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Sorry about that, added the traceback and the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues -

1. You are not considering the last line , since your range is - `for x in range(0,length-1):` - and the `stop` argument of range is exlusive, so it does not go to `length-1` . You actually do not need to get the length of use range, you can simply use `for i, x in enumerate(prgmlist):` . `enumerate()` in each iteration returns the index as well as the current element.

   ```
   for i, x in enumerate(prgmlist, 1):
       prgm[i] = list(x)
   ```
2. Secondly, from your actual code seems like you are defining `cmdx` initially as `0` , but in your for loop (as given above) , you are only starting the index in the dictionary from `1` . So you should define that starting at `1`. Example -

   ```
   stacks, str1, str2, cmdx, cmdy, face, register, cmd = {"now":[]}, 0, 0, 1, 0, "E", 0, None
   ```

   And you should start `cmdy` from `0` . Seems like you had both of them reversed.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like

```
cmd = prgm[x][y]
```

the first part prgm[x] will access the list that's the value for the x key in the dictionary then [y] will pull the yth element from the list.